# Bootstrap 4 modal over modal focus trap lost

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4: by open the first modal, the focus is a trap inside it (you can move the focus with tab key and you will never focus element outside the modal). When you open the second modal the focus is a trap inside it and again you can't focus outside element (this is right).
When you close the second modal the focus will back to the first modal (this is right) but the problem is that if you move the focus with tab key then the focus will go out (after the last focusable modal1 element) from the first modal so it is not trapped anymore in the first modal. Is there is any solution to solve the problem with bootstrap 4?

you can test it in jsfiddle (firefox browser):
https://jsfiddle.net/4cnmvf13/1/

html5:

```
<!-- Modal2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Modal1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        1
        <!-- Button trigger modal2 -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button trigger modal1 -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

css:

```
#exampleModal2 {
  z-index: 200000;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap itself advice against nested modals, so I guess the answer to your question is no...

Comment: Yes but they don't say anything about focus trap. My opinion is that when you open the first modal some properties will add to it and when you open the second modal (not when you close it) on the first one you lost that properties. I think that is sufficient re-add it with .on('hidden.bs.modal') on the second modal. The problem is to understand which propreties is lost in the first modal...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does not handle these kinds of scenario it seems, you can handle the event as it is below to get the required tab-index with in the model

```js
$('#exampleModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#exampleModal').modal("hide");
})

$('#exampleModal2').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#exampleModal').modal("show");
})
```

```css
#exampleModal2 {
  z-index: 1600;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Modal1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        1
        <!-- Button trigger modal2 -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button trigger modal1 -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Comment: which browser you use?
in firefox not work this fix, focus will go outside on the first modal when you close the second one and try to move with tab key

Comment: @lausent i always use chrome check the code in chrome , it will definitely work

Comment: @BathriNathan tested right now in last chrome version and it not work: https://jsfiddle.net/4cnmvf13/4/

Comment: @lausent bootstrap dont not support for these kinds of scenario, so i have provided a simple solution with jquery to over come this issue .please check the code right now.it may help you

Comment: @lausent hey do u check u my code or else do u need any other solution ?